# Missing characters in figure when printed

Tags: xetex, printing

The following plot is displayed on my Mac and chromebook (using either Adobe Reader, Preview and Chrome).
[image: Output in pdf, everything is fine here]

However when I print the document using Adobe Reader (on Mac) many characters are missing:
[image: Photo of the print showing the missing characters]

I searched this site for a solution and found that maybe as it is a plot produced with R and modified with Illustrator, the fonts might not be embedded in the final pdf produced by XeLaTeX. However, a subset of the fonts in the pdf of the plot (here HelveticaNeue Regular and Bold) are embedded in the final document.

Only the figure behave like this. The text, equations, tables and captions print fine otherwise.

As I fear this could happen for the other plots I have in my document and as I have to send it for review, is there a way to insure the plot will be printed correctly (or at all) on any (recent) computer ? Would it be better if I used a raster image for the plot instead of a pdf, in what format then ?

Comment: The problem you describe -- figures look OK on screen, but not when printed out on paper -- sounds like it might be related to an incorrect setup of the printer. Do you have access to a different printer to let you check this hypothesis? Any chance you could reinstall the printer driver from scratch?

Comment: @Mico from your comment I tried to print it with Preview and it worked. The problem must be with Adobe Reader or with the setup I have. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I might consider setting "print as image" by default on the final document before I send it.

Comment: If you go for raster, PNG works well. Personally, this is what I would probably do. Adobe Reader is ubiquitous and it is not worth the risk of alienating a reviewer (assuming this is for something important such as a journal or funding submission).

Comment: In Illustrator, you could convert the text to paths/curves. This way the text is not dependent on fonts at all, but still remains a vector image, which should result in higher quality output and smaller file size.

Comment: @penguinpreferred Thanks. I will try your solution in next time. In the meantime, I changed the font (from HelveticaNeue to Adobe Garamond Pro) of the rotated text and it worked as far as I could see.