# Large symbols in PDF cannot be fully printed

Tags: beamer, pdf, printing

See the following photo taken from printed paper. These symbols are fine when viewed in my laptop, with latest macOS.

Here is the link to the file. [pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-126-game-theory-spring-2016/lecture-notes/MIT14_126S16_bayesian.pdf)

This was $\cap$ in the pdf file.

[image: PI]

This was $\int$ in the pdf file.
[image: int]

This was $\sum$ in the pdf file.
[image: sum]

Comment: Perhaps you should provides us with the code that generated this beamer document. Do you mean 'printing' to paper really?

Comment: This may be a limitation of your PDF viewer or print driver.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I only have the pdf file. I am not the author of the file.

Comment: @JoeLi: Well, what do you expect the users of TeX.SE to do then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This pdf file is compiled in TeX. I observed the symptoms, with no clue how it happened. Just like you went to see a doctor when you're not feel well.

Comment: @JoeLi: But like for many symptoms there maybe many causes  ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's right. I hope someone here can tell me what's the cause so I can fix it.

Comment: But how can you fix the cause, if you haven’t got the LaTeX source?  Full circle in the conversation… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti But we don't know whether the issue is solely due to the source or not, do we?

Comment: Admittedly, we don’t.  Nonetheless, I’m afraid that, without additional information, nobody will be able to diagnose what “disease” affects your PDF file.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti JohnKormylo made a very helpful diagnosis already. Hopefully someone else might find useful contribution as well.

Comment: I still think that, in this question, it is unclear what you are asking: try to investigate the problem yourself, and add whatever information you are able to uncover.  Does the issue show up only in print?  Does it also affect previewing?  Have you tried with different previewers/printers, as John implicitly suggested?  If so, what was the outcome?  I’m ready to withdraw my close vote if you reformulate your question as to give us a fighting chance of finding a positive answer.  **Edit:**  Another hint could be to look at the fonts embedded, or not embedded, in the PDF file.

Comment: Maybe related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220016/missing-characters-in-figure-when-printed

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I think I made it clear that these symbols looks fine in the pdf file. The problem occurred after they were printed. I don't have many printers to try things out. In my personal experience, preview is always exactly the same as printed. That's why it's called preview. So this is weird.

Comment: What do you mean by it was `$\Pi$` in the PDF? Isn't that what you assume (but don't know) was in the *source*? Or did the PDF really include *code* rather than a compiled result for these symbols? And why do you think it would be, say, `$\Pi$` rather than `$\prod$`?

Comment: You have evidently led a sheltered life if this *this* counts as `weird`. Believe me, there are things much weirder than this by far. (E.g. 90% of all serif lower-case `t`s in a document disappear. Only the `t`s, only the lower-case and only the serif. And not even all of those.) Try telling your computer to send the file to the printer as an image. That will probably get it to print correctly even if you are dealing with a fairly dim printer and/or a poor printer driver. This works for me even if the printer is a typographically-challenged photocopier. Usually.

Comment: @cfr Yes you're right, that's what I assumed. And it should be $prod$. I was hoping the greek letter actually get displayed so no one would notice the difference. The PDF does not contain the code. The PDF look almost the same as the photo I took except for these large symbols.

Comment: Can you provide the PDF file?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Sure. I edited in the question.

Comment: Can you try to view and print [this PDF](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/MIT14_126S16_bayesian-3.pdf)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. I'll do that tomorrow morning. But what's the difference?

Comment: @JoeLi I convert your PDF with `ps2pdf14` (from PDF v1.6 to PDF v1.4).

Comment: With Windows 10, and using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2015.023.20056, I can print this successfully with all the fonts correctly displayed.  Worked fine on both Brother HL-2170W and on a Brother HL-5250DN.

Comment: with Chrome PDF Viewer Plug-in I can see and print all the fonts correctly: http://imgur.com/a/KBSBQ

Comment: @PaulGaborit Hi, I printed your file and it works perfect! If you could please add the answer about how exactly did you do it I will accept it!

Comment: I've had issues with evince for windows (so an old version) displaying a pdf fine but failing to print.  This isn't limited to LaTeX pdfs.  So it really could be a viewer issue

Comment: @JoeLi Ok to add an answer... but, for now, your question is closed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original PDF uses PDF version 1.6:

```sh
% file MIT14_126S16_bayesian.pdf
MIT14_126S16_bayesian.pdf: PDF document, version 1.6
```

You can convert this PDF via `ps2pdf` (from PDF version 1.6 to version 1.4 for example):

```sh
% ps2pdf14 MIT14_126S16_bayesian.pdf MIT14_126S16_bayesian-1.4.pdf
```